# How to use Azure Recovery Services Vault azure python package to fetch Disaster Recovery Services details?

Tags: python, azure, oop, data-structures, disaster-recovery

I am trying to fetch the Disaster Recovery Backup details of azure recovery vault services like VM's details, disk details etc. using azure recovery services/ azure recovery backup services client(python). There are no proper examples anywhere in the azure documentation in order to use the client effectively. There are some ways in power shell but I am not eager to learn it.

I have already tried [this](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-python/) but it has no proper examples.

I also am able to create `RecoveryServicesClient` from `azure.mgmt.recoveryservices` but I am unable to use any of its methods to fetch the disk level details of backupVM or backupVM details.

Can some azure/python expert point me to the right direction here?

Comment: If you want to get azure VM backup details, I think you need to package `azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup`. Regarding how to use it, please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/3f6238b2a224df11fa88c6501e078aac96697277/sdk/recoveryservices/azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup/tests

Comment: @JimXu appreciate your interest! I looked into the python test code but isn't it a very vague description of the limited things it can do? Azure CLI is built using the sdk2.0.  If we look at the counterpart boto3 in AWS each method to be performed on the package class is mentioned and arguments defined carefully. Is there some place where we can find usages of `azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup`

Comment: If you want o know how to use the sdk, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup/azure.mgmt.recoveryservicesbackup?view=azure-python

Comment: @JimXu it was the first place i looked into . The methods & attributes seems to be updated just recently. Anyways, Thanks!